# load a dynamic generated stl

Tags: javascript, three.js

My code generates a stl file of an uploaded file with javascript. The stl itself works perfect if I just take the generated string.
But now I have trouble to show it with three.js.

I tried it like this:

```
loader.load( my_generated_stl_string, function ( geometry ) { ...}
```

and get the error:

```
414 (Request-URI Too Long)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load function of the STLLoader class expects the first parameter to be a url to load data from.
You can view the source [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/STLLoader.js).
You will also notice that the STLLoader class has other functions that get called after the expected url is loaded.
So, it looks to me like you might be able to call `parse` instead of `load`.
eg.

```
var geometry = loader.parse(my_generated_stl_string);
```

This is untested though